# How to have separate bookmark toolbars for personal/work purposes that can be hidden?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-addons, bookmarks, addons

Is there an add-on for this? If not, what is the alternative for this purpose: to separate work and personal bookmarks? I already do something similar with the tab groups extension and I need this for the bookmarks. Is it possible to easily toggle from one Firefox account to another, just like in Chromium with Google accounts?

I must specify that I want to see the bookmarks so I can't just put the bookmarks in two bookmark folders.

## Update 1

I do not want a separate profile for work because I want to have Firefox Sync enabled and a single Firefox account. One of the reasons is that I use common services for which I would have to change the password in both profiles.

To put it in other words, is there a FF extension that shows on the new-tab page (which is for me currently empty) a specific bookmarks directory that can be changed in the settings of that extension or somewhere so I can do it in less than 1 minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FireFox there are User Profiles, which you can switch in the menu. All your personal data, like the bookmarks are stored in these profiles, so switching the profile will switch the bookmarks, the extensions, the cache, the history and so on. Like this you can have two completely different setups for your work and your personal browsing activity.

Here [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles] you can read more about profiles. I hope this solves your problems.

Comment: I have updated the question with a new section, "Update 1". Please take a look at it if you can and wish to help me further.

Comment: Maybe [this] (https://superuser.com/questions/1457692/creating-multiple-sync-profiles-in-firefox) is helpful as well... Sorry but I do not know many Firefox-Extensions as most of them are quite suspicious because they are not reviewed in a way that I would consider secure. If you find something open-source, you can think about, but if you want to store your credentials, and want the Extension to manage them, I would be very cautious. Sorry about the formatting, on my phone it is quite difficult...